# How to resolve SocketException?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, unicenta

I am using UnicentaPOS software and I have connected database from remote server. I am getting below warning after no activity for a few minutes on software. I have researched the issue and tried solutions given online. but, nothing is working in my case.

****com.openbravo.basic.BasicException: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,069,594 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,069,610 milliseconds ago.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,069,594 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,069,610 milliseconds ago.
java.net.SocketException: 
Connection reset by peer: socket write error****

Comment: You should first check if maybe your MySQL server config has a short idle timeout. The socket write error could also indicate a network issue, but in all likelihood, MySQL closed the connection because it exceeded some timeout or max lifetime setting.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel I tried to increase wait timeout variable, but not sure it keeps giving me an exception. Is there any other variable I need to change?